# ReactJS and material-ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the RaisedButton's background color but when I use a className, the name of the class is in the div that the RaisedButton autogenerate.

This is the button

```
<RaisedButton className="access-login" label="Acceder" type="submit"/>
```

This is the css

```
.access-login{
    background-color: #d17817 !important;
}
```

Any ideas ?

**Edit**
I want to add a class, not put css inline.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

A quick way that works without messing with the theme is this:

```
<RaisedButton backgroundColor="#d17817" label="Acceder" type="submit"/>
```

Comment: But if I want to use the class ?